# Help with logic within generator function

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, generator

I'm trying to create a generator function:

```
def combinations(iterable, r, maxGapSize):
    maxGapSizePlusOne = maxGapSize+1

    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))

    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):        
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:     
                break
        else:
            return

        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1

        previous = indices[0]
        for k in indices[1:]:
            if k-previous>maxGapSizePlusOne:
                isGapTooBig = True
                break
            previous = k
        else:
            isGapTooBig = False

        if not isGapTooBig:
            print(indices)


combinations(("Aa","Bbb","Ccccc","Dd","E","Ffff",),2,1)
```

I'm printing out the indices that I wish to use to select the elements from the argument called 'iterable' for debugging purposes. This gives me:

```
[0, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 4]
[3, 5]
[4, 5]
```

Ignoring `[0,1]` as this is produced elsewhere...

This is exactly what I want  but I'm guessing my code it over complicated and inefficient. The size of `iterable` is likely to be in the thousands and it's likely `maxGapSize < 5`.

Any tips to help me do this better?

Comment: You didn't explain what it's supposed to do.

Comment: When you have code that already works but you want to make it better, the place to ask is at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much of your code looks exactly like the [Python code for itertools.combination](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). The CPython implementation of `itertools.combination` is written in C. The documentation linked to above shows Python-equivalent code.

You can speed up the function by simply using `itertools.combination` instead of using the Python-equivalent code:

```
import itertools as it
def mycombinations(iterable, r, maxGapSize):
    maxGapSizePlusOne = maxGapSize+1    
    for indices in it.combinations(range(len(iterable)),r):
        previous = indices[0]
        for k in indices[1:]:
            if k-previous>maxGapSizePlusOne:                    
                break
            previous = k
        else:
            yield indices   
            # print(indices)
```

You can use [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) to compare the relative speed of alternate implementations this way:

**original version:**

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'list(test.combinations(("Aa","Bbb","Ccccc","Dd","E","Ffff",),2,1))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.9 usec per loop
```

versus

**using `itertools.combination:`**

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'list(test.mycombinations(("Aa","Bbb","Ccccc","Dd","E","Ffff",),2,1))'
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.2 usec per loop
```

---

The code above produces all combinations, including the initial combination, `range(len(iterable))`. I think it is more beautiful to leave it that way. But if you really want to remove the first combination, you could use

```
def mycombinations(iterable, r, maxGapSize):
    ...
    comb=it.combinations(range(len(iterable)),r)
    next(comb)
    for indices in comb:
```

---

By the way, the function `combinations` does not really depend on `iterable`. It only depends on the length of `iterable`. Therefore, it would be better to make the call signature

```
def combinations(length, r, maxGapSize):
```